# How to export all accounts or everything Outlook 2010 Windows to Outlook for Mac (latest version)

Tags: windows, macos, microsoft-outlook-2010, migration, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have my PC with 23 email accounts and mega messages that I  would like to transfer to my new MacBook.  All I really have to move is the account settings and it can pull all the mail again.  I saw the way to do it with a registry entry, but that won't work on Mac OSX.  Anyone know a way to do this?  Thanks in advance

Capn

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Migration assistant on your MAC.

It will do the job for you.

You can find it in the Utility folder.